# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/theun3wr/public_html/author.php on line 11

Tags: wordpress, get-headers

Since I shifted to multi-domain hosting in December, I'm plagued with errors on my website. There have been so many issues that I've lost track of them. And every day I end up with a shocking new error that I'm clueless about.

One of the most recent ones being not able to access author profile on my website - http://www.theunbiasedblog.com/author/nikhil

Rest of the website is working alright except these things:

1. Author profiles (Mentioned Above) this error

   ```
   Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/theun3wr/public_html/author.php on line 11
   ```
2. Tag links on the site (http://www.theunbiasedblog.com/tag/windows) give this error

   ```
   Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/theun3wr/public_html/tag.php on line 11
   ```
3. Category links on the site (theunbiasedblogcom/category/tech)

   ```
   Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/theun3wr/public_html/category.php on line 11
   ```

I'm not able to figure out what to do with `get_header()` that is on line 11 of all these non functional links. As a result I've 30K 404 errors from google.

@prakashrao
In wp-includes/general-template.php

I've this -

```
 /**
 * Load header template.
 *
 * Includes the header template for a theme or if a name is specified then a
 * specialised header will be included.
 *
 * For the parameter, if the file is called "header-special.php" then specify
 * "special".
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @param string $name The name of the specialised header.
 */
  function get_header( $name = null ) {
  /**
 * Fires before the header template file is loaded.
 *
 * The hook allows a specific header template file to be used in place of the
 * default header template file. If your file is called header-new.php,
 * you would specify the filename in the hook as get_header( 'new' ).
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
 * @since 2.8.0 $name parameter added.
 *
 * @param string $name Name of the specific header file to use.
 */
do_action( 'get_header', $name );

$templates = array();
$name = (string) $name;
if ( '' !== $name )
    $templates[] = "header-{$name}.php";

$templates[] = 'header.php';

// Backward compat code will be removed in a future release
if ('' == locate_template($templates, true))
    load_template( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/theme-compat/header.php');
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]make sure you have this function defined in your active theme

```
function get_header( $name = null ) {
    /**
     * Fires before the header template file is loaded.
     *
     * The hook allows a specific header template file to be used in place of the
     * default header template file. If your file is called header-new.php,
     * you would specify the filename in the hook as get_header( 'new' ).
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     * @since 2.8.0 $name parameter added.
     *
     * @param string $name Name of the specific header file to use.
     */
    do_action( 'get_header', $name );

    $templates = array();
    $name = (string) $name;
    if ( '' !== $name )
        $templates[] = "header-{$name}.php";

    $templates[] = 'header.php';

    // Backward compat code will be removed in a future release
    if ('' == locate_template($templates, true))
        load_template( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/theme-compat/header.php');
}
```

Comment: In functions.php of your active theme

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_header() (previously declared in /home/theun3wr/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:8) in /home/theun3wr/public_html/wp-includes/general-template.php on line 49

Comment: can u please provide a screen shot of your directory structure which is uploaded at server.. and one screenshot of in wp-content

Comment: Here you  go

!http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1051847/7fb04e3f2a406cf0c28d356b5fe816b4

!http://goo.gl/uNgB3u

!http://goo.gl/XOgiQk

!http://goo.gl/HMRjt8

Comment: I really appreciate the time and efforts you are spending to help me out. Can't thank you enough, do let me know If I can do anything for you.

Comment: no worries , i think you have installed wordpress inside a project build in some kind of framework  I guess.

Comment: No, there is no framework. I just moved my websites from different hosts to one single domain hosting. Therefore you see a few more site names in the public_html folder

Comment: Error which you are getting is Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/theun3wr/public_html/author.php on line 11.

But the author.php never should be under public html folder.. its inside wp-content/themes/<your active theme>

Try to move all the templates files in that folder.. please see the files in the image (attached in answer) that should be under wp-content/themes/<your theme folder>

Comment: if there is an author.php file inside public html folder remove that

Comment: I renamed author.php to author.php.old to see how it effects once removed. The error is this now - http://www.theunbiasedblog.com/122.162.175.79/author/nikhilwww.theunbiasedblog.comMozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36404